# PHP Post data to API page

Tags: php

I have this PHP class for an API:

```
class Integra {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->api_key = 'API-XXXXXXX';
        $this->api_salt = '';
    }

    public function build_query($type, $data = array())
    {
        //$salted = hash_hmac('md5', $this->api_key, $this->api_salt);

        //$data['api_key'] = $salted;
        //$data['key'] = $this->api_key;
        $params = $data;

        $data_string = json_encode($params);  

        $ch = curl_init('http://domain.com/api.php');                                                               
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
        'Content-Type: application/json')
        );

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $response = json_decode($response);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

so this is posting data to the relevant page/function.

I want to be able to return the data as objects, i have tried the following on the page that the data is being posted to but nothing is being returned.

What have i done wrong?

```
<?php
return array('status' => 'test', 'reason' => 'test2');
?>
```

Here is how i call the class and function:

```
$Integra = new Integra();
$output = $Integra->build_query('check_system.php');

echo $output->reason;
echo $output->status;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type cast it to `object` after initializing the array.

```
return (object) array('status' => 'test', 'reason' => 'test2');
```

https://3v4l.org/dKWAT

Comment: i am getting this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sites/pjford.co.uk/public_html/test.php on line 46 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/sites/pjford.co.uk/public_html/test.php on line 47

Comment: Dump the variable `$response` (the freshly json decoded one) and look what you really get from the API.

Comment: Dump the return of `curl_exec()`, you may know then what is wrong.

Comment: I just noticed you have in `$this->domain` `domain.com/api` and when you initialize curl, you fill it with `$this->domain.'/api/' . $type` which makes it `domain.com/api/api/$type`, I think it should just be `$this->domain.'/' . $type`.

Comment: check my update, i have just made a change so its posting directly to one page, its still returning the same error

Comment: any ideas how to ensure i can return the data?

Comment: Well, first you need to ensure you get something from the API page (you can connect to it and it will print an appropriate response).

Comment: how can i test this ?

Comment: @charlie Basic debugging includes using `curl_getinfo()` http://php.net/curl_getinfo

Comment: what option is best to use to ensure its connecitng?